# CakePHP adding to multiple tables from one view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

can someone provide an explanation for me?

I've got a database where I'm trying to update 4 tables from one page, Organizations, OrganizationsDetails, Account, AccountRoles.  The add view itself would contain fields for the Account and the Organization.  When I call the OrganizationsController add function, I want to then call add on AccountController, AccountRolesController (set Account as an administrator role), and OrganizationDetailsController (set that Account as the administrator for that specific Organization).

Should I be using components for this?  When I call add() on the Organizations, I always intend to perform these steps - never solely create the Organizations entry below.  Should I be doing this directly in that function or some other method?

Let me know if I need to explain more, thanks!

EDIT:  Added the four models below:
Organization

```
class Organization extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Account' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' => 'organization_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
    public $hasOne = array(
        'OrganizationDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'OrganizationDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'organization_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

OrganizationDetail

```
class OrganizationDetail extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Organization' => array(
            'className' => 'Organization',
            'foreignKey' => 'organization_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Account' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

AccountRole

```
class AccountRole extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Account' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Role' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Account

```
class Account extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Organization' => array(
            'className' => 'Organization',
            'foreignKey' => 'organization_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

    public $hasOne = array(
        'OrganizationDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'OrganizationDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'AccountRole' => array(
            'className' => 'AccountRole',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Comment: Which version are you use in cakephp ?

Comment: 2.7.  I'm also thinking, should this be a new custom Model querying those 4 tables?  Or is the rule generally 1 Model - 1 DB table.

Comment: Could you show your model associations? If all of these models are properly associated with each other, you should be able to set values in the `$this->request->data` array and perform the appropriate type of save() method to capture all the related data in one go from the OrganizationsController.

Comment: Added the four model associations above.

Comment: I suggested [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10367022) but was rejected. Please edit the question yourself to reduce its length.

Answer (score 0):

You've got wrong the whole MVC idea. Controllers should not call methods in other controllers (or at least not in this scenario).

The right approach would be to set up OrganizationsController->add() so that it saves all the data by independent calls to each Model->save($data), or by using

```
Organization->saveAssociated($data,array('deep' => true))
```

Your form fields need to be named properly for this to work. For example:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Organization', array('action' => 'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('Organization.name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Account.0.name', array('label' => 'Account name'));
echo $this->Form->input('OrganizationDetail.details', array('label' => 'Org. Details'));
echo $this->Form->input('Account.0.AccountRole.id', array('label' => 'Account Role'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
```

However, you may get into trouble if you try to go too many levels deep. If you find yourself in this situation, it's probably because you data model is flawed.

This is what **your data model currently looks like:**

[image: Data Model]

This is what I believe **it should look like:**

[image: Normalized Data Model]

It is critical to have your data model right before you start coding. It can save you many headaches!